# Pointer to corresponding page etc

Tags: back-referencing

I implemented glossary and a bibliograpghy in a report.

A few days ago, everytime I had `\acrshrt{the_word}`, the pdf version would create a pointer from the actual word to its meaning in the glossary and vice versa. However it seems this feature has vanished in the following versions of my report and I can't seem to know why and what happened.

Can someone enlighten me on what's reponsible for causing this ?

***Previously*** : [image], [image]

***Now*** : [image], [image]

Comment: Please tell us what you have done via a MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`). As it is your question is like "something has changed in my document but I won't tell you what". -- GOM

Comment: Yeah I get it haha turns out I don't really now either what had changed - I had changed the order of importation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I found :

Turns out for some very **very** ***VERY*** obsucre reasons, importing the `hyperref` package before the `glossaries` package solved it ..

Guess I'll stop importing my packages in an alphabetical order x)

Comment: The "common wisdom" is indeed to load `hyperref` as late as possible. Otherwise it interacts badly with a number of other packages.

Comment: Guess I'll know this from now on :D